# AVFoundation play sound swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I try to play sound with Swift 2.0
If I write 'try' without '!' I got error
"Errors thrown from here are not handled" 
And AVAudioPlayer is not Optional why Xcode request 'try!'
If I write 'try!' my app crash 
"unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

```
class TouchViewController: UIViewController {
var soundPath:NSURL? 
...................
 //Play Bipsound
        do { soundPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Bipsound", ofType: "wav")!)
           var sound = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundPath!, fileTypeHint: nil)
            sound.prepareToPlay()
            sound.play() }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    var soundPath:NSURL? 

    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Bipsound", ofType: "wav") {
        soundPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        do {
            let sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundPath!, fileTypeHint:nil)
            sound.prepareToPlay()
            sound.play()
        } catch {
            //Handle the error
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Pretend you've never seen the `!` force-unwrapping operator in Swift before and stop using it entirely. It's basically the "Crash if this optional contains nil" operator. Use "if let" style optional binding or try/catch as outlined by @LLooggaann in his excellent answer. (voted)

Comment: Agreed. I did use it there on `soundPath` but only because I 100% know it's safe from the line above, and I'm assuming it's declared as an optional for a reason.  Could always have added one extra `if let` to be super-safe.